# Create object from another object in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, class, object

I want to copy some documents from MongoDB from one DB to another, but only specific properties of this document. Given a source document with the format:

```
{topic: string, email: {enabled: boolean}, mobile: {enabled: boolean}}
```

I want to insert into the new DB something with the following format:

```
{topic: string, email: {enabled: boolean}}
```

I am doing something like this in order to create the new object that will be inserted:

```
class Document(object):
    topic = ""
    email = object()

def make_document(topic, email):
    document = Document()
    document.topic = topic
    document.email = email
    return document

 settings = source_db.collectionName.find({})

 for setting in settings:
    new_setting = make_document(setting.topic, setting.email)

    db.collectionName.insertOne(new_setting)
```

My doubts are:

- am I creating the new object correctly ?
- is the declaration of the email property in the class correct (e.g. email = object())
- is there a better (or a more correct) way to do it?

I am really new with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way of initializing variable(class attribute) inside a class,

```
class Document(object):
    def __init__(self, topic, email):
    self.topic = topic
    self.email = email

settings = source_db.collectionName.find({})

for setting in settings:
    new_setting = Document(setting.topic, setting.email)
    db.collectionName.insertOne(new_setting)
```

*Question to you:* Since the response you're getting it as `dictionary/json`, any reason why you trying to make it as class?

```
{topic: string, email: {enabled: boolean}, mobile: {enabled: boolean}}
```

**Update:** Then you can simply achieve this through dictionary parsing. Check this one,

```
 settings = source_db.collectionName.find({})

 for setting in settings:
    new_data = {"topic": setting["topic"], "email": setting["email"]}
    db.collectionName.insertOne(new_data)
```

Comment: no reason in particular, all I am trying to do is create a new object based on the document returned by Mongo, where I only have a part of the fields of the original document. If there is a better way to achieve that, I am more than open to suggestions.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out.